# cx_Freeze No file named locket

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I am trying to create .exe program for my python program with python styp.py build , however the terminal shows an error  `raise ConfigError( cx_Freeze.exception.ConfigError: No file named C:\Users\ksabitova\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\locket-0.2.1-py3.8.egg\locket\__init__.py (for module locket)`

It worked before on previous pc, however, today I've changed my pc to new one and the same function doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue today with cx freeze and locket. I solved it by updating locket using:

```
conda install -c anaconda locket
```

in anaconda prompt

Answer (score 0):

do you have do cd the_path before ? I think yes but just in case
otherwise try to change `/` into `\` or inversely...
sorry if my english is bad ...have a good day!

Comment: I didn;t understand you. Sorry. It worked before on the old pc.

Comment: when you add a path maybe use '/' instead of '\' or use '\' instead of '/'